# How to POST to another site with just a url

Tags: json, rest, http, post, get

A service provider is supposed to forward messages on to an endpoint (specified by me) but all I get to give them is a URL. How can I make this work.

I have signed up to a satellite service and I am trying make the first steps with their cloud API. I have hardware which sends simple messages over their satellite infrastructure to their cloud services. The provide the user (me) with a dashboard type interface to register the hardware as well as a desitnation (or multiple destinations) each destination is a single url. I dont get to specify usernames, passwords, code or anything just a single url. The service says

"the data will be forwarded to the pre-registered http(s) endpoint (the URL I have given them). Data is sent as a http POST request with Content-Type: application/json. All data is accompanied by an endpoint reference, timestamp, a unique identifier (UUID), and a digital signature that may be used to verify that the data originated from Myriota. Multiple packets may be batched into a single request."

I have a website so to start with I just want to get a single message to display on my page. I have completed and tested the code to display posts by GETing from https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts. This works.
the URL that I have given the service provider is the same as above. But none of the data reaches my site.

I dont really know how the data exchange or handshaking works here but I assume that for a third party to post to my site, they would need to include some sort of authentication. can this authentication data be included in the url? what is the authentication data? is it my Wordpress username and password? Is it safe send this data in a url? Can I turn off authentication so that anyone can post to my site? surely that isnt safe?

I have minimal experience with web development but plenty with embedded systems, I am working with a young software engineer and he is stumped also. together we have burned nearly a whole week on this so I have bit the bullet and turned to stackoverflow to see if anyone can help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try and ask only one question per post, else you might not get an answer at all, or some of your questions will remain unanswered.

Comment: Thanks Badja, my question is. "How to POST to another site with just a URL?" The rest is just my thought process.

Comment: This question looks a lot like yours, is this how you doing it or please provide your code https://stackoverflow.com/q/57317062/10634638

Comment: I have found a workaround by creating a custom endpoint. I have found this little gem https://reqbin.com/ which has let me test and confirm that the post is arriving without the need for authorisation. Unfortunately, I can not post an answer because I am too new to stack overflow