# GET Request Returning Same Info from a Randomized Endpoint

Tags: javascript, rest, api, http

I'm accessing the QuotesOnDesign randomized endpoint: `https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&` and for some reason I'm getting the same value returned everytime, even with no-cache enabled. This happens in every browser and in Postman.

No, idea what I can do to fix this, as it was working literally just a few weeks ago. My last commit was the end of June and it was working fine then.

My function that accesses the endpoint is as follows:

```
  httpCallout(){
    fetch('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&', {cache: "no-cache"})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const quote = data[0].content;
      console.log(quote);
      this.setState({
        quote: quote,
        author: data[0].title
      });
    });
  }
```

In theory, it should return a new quote every time, as it previously was. But now, I'm simply receiving the same data every time.

Comment: If you actually visit that endpoint with your browser, it's returning the exact same quote every time. What makes you think the endpoint is randomized?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the API itself. Test out in your browser the results from that same query but `filter[posts_per_page]` with different values. For any `n` posts_per_page, it will return the same `n` values.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior In their API documentation, https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/, that is listed as the access point to receive a new random quote. Also, as stated, just a few weeks ago it was producing a random quote each and every time. So I'm not sure if the problem was in my code, or if it has something to do with the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that website uses client-side code to pick some kind of a starter value (perhaps a random seed, or an ID, or a page number, or something?) to start with and includes that ID in the request (e.g. https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_=1564694860977).

Since you're not including that value in your request, it's apparently using a default value, and since it's the same value every time you're getting the same results every time.

Comment: I believe the issue falls into the API. I was previously using RNG to select the ID, however the `rand` argument in the URL used to work just fine.